# How can the Delphi x64 compilation time be speeded up?

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, delphi-xe4

While testing compilation speed both x32 and x64, I have found that x64 compilation is twice slower than x32. This case is described here: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=112845.

In case when I compile project with compiled VCL dcu's that x64 compilation is third slower than x32 with same compiled dcu's.

Is it available any method for increasing x64 compilation performance under Delphi XE4?

Comment: Are you talking about how long it takes to compile, or how fast the resulting executable is?

Comment: Faster computer, faster disk, shorter search paths.

Comment: @LURD x64 compiler will still be around 3-4 times slower.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, compared to the x32 compiler, yes. But the question was how to speed up the x64 compilation time.

Comment: @LURD OK, I took it slightly differently. I took the comparison with x86 compiler to indicate that asker thinks the x64 compiler is deficient, and that some action can be taken to make it perform the same as the x86 compiler. Obviously there is no such switch. In my experience, both the x86 and x64 compilers are CPU bound so only a better CPU/mobo/memory combo will help.

Comment: Get a solid state disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Delphi x64 compiler is indeed much slower than the x86 compiler. Short of re-writing the compiler, or getting better hardware, there's nothing you can do to speed it up.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what the current bottleneck is, eg would more cpu power speed it up or more i/o's (ssd) or more ram

Comment: @Remko compiling my code, it is cpu bound. x64 compiler probably not as optimised as x86, and also x64 code gen is just harder.